# Wordpress admin doesn't have permissions in wp-admin

Tags: wordpress

I've been asked to check a Wordpress installation where no user has access to wp-admin directory, not even the admin. I've tried every solution I found on Internet without success:

- The main site loads fine, with all the styles and articles there, so the database can be accessed.
- Directories and files have the right permissions (644 for files, 755 for directories).
- Tables prefixes seems to be fine.
- I've tried to disable plugins (renaming the plugins directory) and restore a default .htaccess with no luck.
- Users can log-in even if they get the page saying that they have no permissions for wp-admin pages. After logged in, I can go to the home page and I see the upper bar with commands like new post, add users, etc. but if I try to use any of them, then I get the no permission page.
- I've checked the Admin permissions in the SQL database and seem to be fine.
- wp-admin/about.php loads (without CSS) so the directory is accessible.
- I've tried enabling the WP_DEBUG flag but the debug is not helpful.

I'm running out of options of what to check next, any advice will be very welcome.

Comment: Have you tried to update wordpress

Comment: Yes, I tried to update to the latest one following the command-line updating instructions from Wordpress, but I'm having he same issue.

Comment: Hi @siritinga, did you ever solve this issue? I've been through your very helpful list (thank you!) but I'm unsure what to do next.

Answer (score 5):

This issue is caused by WordPress table prefixes having been poorly renamed.

Simply renaming table prefixes from `old_` (the old prefix) to `new_` (the new prefix) will mess up permissions, and users won't be able to access `/wp-admin` any more (even admins).

To properly rename table prefixes, you also need to rename some entries (6 to be exact) in `new_options` and `new_usermeta`.

Here's the query you want to run:

```sql
/* Renaming prefixes in new_options */
UPDATE `new_options`
SET `option_name` = REPLACE( option_name, 'old_', 'new_' )
WHERE `option_name` LIKE 'old_%';

/* Renaming prefixes in new_usermeta */
UPDATE `new_usermeta`
SET `meta_key` = REPLACE( meta_key, 'old_', 'new_')
WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'old_%';
```

Comment: I tried this and didn’t work. Finally, it was something related to a security plugin and some rewrite rules for http and https. It was over a year ago and I don’t remember the details.

Comment: This is correct! In my case the `wp_user_roles` option needed to be renamed to `wp_new_user_roles`. After that I was able to access `/wp-admin` again.